# how to cross compile node-gyp for ARM

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack, node-gyp

I create a node application wich need to create from a C program a node module.I used SWIG (Simple wrapper Interface Generator) to do that and I got the node module.The application run successefuly on my PC.I want now to cross compile my application to run it on Beaglebone Black.I run this command:

```
node-gyp --arch=arm configure
```

it works very well but when I run :

```
node-gyp build
```

I got this message:

```
    module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: /home/user/a/build/Release/example.node: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/a/app.js:21:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I think that the problem is related to swig version.But I didn't succeed to install it on the beagleBone Black.